# How to query WhereAnd in Laravel with relationships?

Tags: eloquent, laravel-5.3

I have a model named `Tutor`and it has many `Subjects` `hasMany() relationship`.
I want to write a query that can retrieve all the tutors having subjects Physics and Math.

The table structure of the Subjects is as follows:

```
id | title | tutor_id
```

What is the best way to achieve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get all the tutors having `subjects` Physics and Math both then you can write your query as:

```
Tutor::whereHas('subjects', function($q) {
      $q->where('title', 'physics')
    })
    ->whereHas('subjects', function($q) {
        $q->where('title', 'maths')
    })
    ->get();
```

Comment: Thanks for helping me. I forget to mention the one thing. The number of subjects will be from query string and can be any of any number i.e. 5 subjects or 3 subjects. How can I do now?

Answer (score 0):

```
$tutors = Tutor::whereHas('subjects', function($q) {
                $q->where('title', 'physics')
                  ->orWhere('title', 'maths');
            })->get();
```

I'm not sure if this exact code would work or not, But you get the idea.
To explain, `subjects` is the relationship between `Tutor` and `Subject` and `title` should be the field name in `subject` table.

Comment: I am looking for AND operations not the OR. Thanks for contributions.

Comment: Remove the or, you'll have and.